# Un-Definded variable error when not logged on.

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I've an error stating "Notice: Undefined variable: user_data" only when no one is logged in, when someone is logged in, it says Hello (Users name)

Here is the piece of code that echos the name

```
"Hello, <?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?>!"
```

Is there anyway that it can just say hello, when no user is logged in, instead of the error message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like the previous answers do not really explain what is happening, so I'll try to be more elaborate here.

What both of them do is make use of a `ternary operator`, which I like to refer to as an "immediate if", you can think of it as the following snippet on one line:

```
if ($condition) {  
  echo "this";  
} else {
  echo "that";
}
```

or, with the ternary operator:

```
echo $condition ? "this" : "that"; // prints this if condition is true, that if false.
```

What you really need to solve your problem, is check if your variable is set with `isset`, isset checks if a variable is set, so using that in an if condition, will you solve your error.

Example, and also the answer to your question:

```
if (isset($user_data['first_name'])) { 
  echo 'Hello, ' . $user_data['first_name']; 
} else {
  echo 'Hello!';
}
```

So while the ternary operator is more convienient to use here, it is not required to solve your problem, only `isset` in a check to verify it is set, is required.

That said, both of them do solve your problem, it's just less readable, and may be a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just:

```
Hello <?php echo isset($user_data['first_name']) ? ", ".$user_data['first_name']: ''; ?>!
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if variable exists before using it,

```
$username = isset($user_data['first_name']) ? $user_data['first_name'] : ""; 
echo "Hello ".$username ."!";
```